# pyspark/dataframe - groupby(s), schema transformation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to perform some transformation to get a desired output:

Before:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 
--------------------------------
NBA    | BULLS   | ['Michael', 'Jordan', '23'] 
NBA    | BULLS   | ['Scottie', 'Pippen', '33'] 
NBA    | LAKERS  | ['Kobe', 'Bryant', '24']
```

After:

```
Column 1 | Column 4 
--------------------------------
NBA    | [BULLS : [['Michael', 'Jordan', '23'],['Scottie', 'Pippen', '33']] 
          ,LAKERS : ['Kobe', 'Bryant', '24']]
```

Schema-wise

Before:

```
root
|-- string
|-- string
|-- struct
    |-- string
    |-- string
    |-- int
```

After:

```
root
|-- string
|-- array:string
    |-- array:struct
        |-- string
        |-- string
        |-- int
```

Edit:

With suggestion, I was able to do this:

```
df.groupby('Column 1', 'Column 2')
   .agg(collect_list(struct('Column 3')).alias('Column 4'))
   .groupby('Column 1')
   .agg(collect_list(struct('Column 2', 'Column 4')).alias('Column 5'))
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Looks like it would be possible with two consecutive groupbys.

Comment: You are right, i wasn't thinking straight. I've updated my question with an answer.

Comment: Glad you could solve it :)